# onClick on loop elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, onclick

I need to add onClick event to loop elements:

```
<div id="try"><div/>
<div id="boxes"><div/>

<script>

var x=1;
var boxes=[];
while(x<=7){
boxes[x++]=['<div class="colorbox">whatever now, because it will be  colored boxes</div>'];}
document.getElementById("boxes").innerHTML=boxes;

var i = document.getElementsByClassName('colorbox');
document.write(i);
i.onclick = function(){doit(1, 2);}

function doit(a, b){
    document.getElementById("try").innerHTML=a + b;}
<script>
```

I don't know why onclick event doesn't work in this example. Console doesn't give any mistakes. What could be wrong? 'document.write(i)' shows, that var i is nor empty nither undefinited. It's just html object.

Comment: You have to stop posting answers as extensions of your question

Comment: Does this end up giving you two of each `.colorbox` in the DOM?

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` uses the plural "Elements" and hence returns a collection.  If there is only a single element that matches the class selector, it will return a collection with one element.

Hence, you need to attach your handler to the element itself, rather than the entire array.  As you've tagged your question `jQuery`, I'd suggest using jQuery (which will attach the handler to each element in the array):

```
var x=1;
var boxes=[];
while(x <= 7) {
    boxes[x++] = ['<div class="colorbox">whatever now, because it will be  colored boxes</div>'];
}

document.getElementById("boxes").innerHTML = boxes;

var i = document.getElementsByClassName('colorbox');

document.write(i);

$(i).on('click', function () {
  doit(1, 2);
});

function doit (a, b) {
    document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when I use `$('.colorbox')` instead of `$(i)`, remove all parts with `i` variable and change `.on` event to `.click` event:

```
var x=1;
var boxes=[];
while(x<=7){
boxes[x++]=['<div class="colorbox">whatever now, because it`ll be colored boxes</div>'];}
document.getElementById("boxes").innerHTML=boxes;

$('.colorbox').click(function () {
  doit(1, 2);
});

function doit(a, b){
    document.getElementById("try").innerHTML=a + b;}
```